# Recursive/looping calculations of new generation in The Game of Life

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array, mouseevent, composition

everyone.

Next generation in my [Game Of Life](http://www.bitstorm.org/gameoflife/) application (Link is example application) is calculated correcly. Game works as expected, but you must press "Next" each time you want a new generation. I'm having problem implementing a "Start"-button to loop generations. (See link for difference between "next" and "start".)

It's obvious I need some kind of loop inside the ActionListener class. I've tried calling nextGen() inside the actionListener recursivly while a private boolean is true. The program crashes. I've also tried setting some kind of wait, but it does not matter.

It really DOES do 10 iterations if I place 10 lines of nextGen(); inside the listener, so I'm guessing I need some kind of wait here. (The problem beeing memory.)

Hope you can help me out on this. :)

The next generation is calculated this way.

ActionListener class:

```
public class GameOfLifeListener implements ActionListener
{

    // IMPORTANT: GameOfLifeGrid contains the GameOfLife collection!
    private GameOfLifeGrid gameOfLife;



    public GameOfLifeListener ( GameOfLifeGrid g ) 
    {
        this.gameOfLife = g;
     }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
    {
        // Get actionCommand
        String ac = e.getActionCommand();

        if ( ac.equals("next") ) 
        {
             // Method calculates next generation
             nextGen();
        }
        if ( ac.equals("start") ) 
        {
             // ADDED CODE: See class GameOfLifeGrid in bottom.
             gameOfLife.start();
        }
    }

    private void nextGen ( ) 
    {
        // Get Next generation
        gameOfLife.getCollection().nextGen();

        // Repaint
        gameOfLife.repaint();
    }
}
```

The actionListener runs nextGen() on the GameOfLife object when button "next" is pressed. How the nextGen() method works is not important, but here it along with some parts of the GameOfLife class

```
public class GameOfLife extends CellCollection
{
    // Temporary array for new generation . We must add next generations alive cells HERE.
    // Else the calculations of the current generation will fail.
    private Cell[][] nextGen = null;

    public void nextGen ( ) 
    {
        // Create the new Array holding next generation
        prepareNextCollection();

        // Iterate the whole grid
        for ( int row = 0; row < super.rows; row++ ) 
        {
            for ( int col = 0; col < super.cols; col++ ) 
            {
                 ruleOne(row, col);
            }
        }

        // Set the new collection to superClass. 
        // Super class holds the collection that will be drawn
        super.setCollection(nextGen);
    }


    private void ruleOne ( int row, int col ) 
    {
        // Calculations not important. It works like expected.
    }

    private void prepareNextCollection ( ) 
    {
        this.nextGen = new Cell[rows][cols];
    }
```

This is selected parts of the GameOfLifeGrid class. It draws the grid and the alive cells (Cell array).

```
public class GameOfLifeGrid extends Grid
{

    private GameOfLife collection = null;

    // ADDED MEMBERS: Timer, int
    private Timer timer; 
    private int updateEachMilliSec = 100; // Used in program. Not in this code

    @Override
    public void paintComponent ( Graphics g )
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawCells(g);
    }

    private void drawCells ( Graphics g ) 
    {
        for ( int row = 0; row < rows; row++ ) 
        {
            for ( int col = 0; col < cols; col++ )
            {
                if ( ! collection.isEmptyPos(row, col) ) 
                {
                    g.fillRect(super.calcX(col), super.calcY(row), cellSize, cellSize);
                }
            }
        } 
    }

    // ADDED METHOD!
    public void start() 
    {
        // Create a timer object. The timer will send events each 100 ms.
        // The events will be caught by the ActionListener returned from
        // nextGenlistener(). VOILA!

        timer = new Timer(100, nextGenlistener());

        // Start sending events to be caught!
        timer.start();
    }

    // ADDED METHOD! The ActionListener who will catch the events sent by timer.
    private ActionListener nextGenlistener () 
    {
        return new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                // Get next generation
                collection.nextGen();

                // Repaint
                repaint();
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you try to loop with Thread.sleep() in the actionPerformed method, you are blocking the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Nothing can get repainted until you release control of the thread, so your repaint requests spool up and fire off all at once when your actionPerformed method finishes.

The simple solution is to use a javax.swing.Timer to fire events at a regular interval, something along these lines:

```
new Timer(5000, new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    panel.repaint();
  }
}).start();
```

Comment: It took me a long time to get this right. I never would've found out without a point in the right direction. Thank you!